# Variable fonts color in Pie Chart Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have made a Pie Chart with 3 colors. "Red, Blue, Green".
What I want is that the font color changes to white when slice is red and the rest is black. Is that possible?

In my data I have made a column for font color.

Comment: What do you mean by font color? Is it the color of the hover text? Can you share a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Shared a example

Answer (score 0):

[example of pie with different font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z32g2.png)

> it is the text in de slices, No hover...  Example is how it must be.